# How can we clear the value of paramter in dialogflow using nodejs API

Tags: dialogflow-es

**NODEJS**

```
dialogContext = {
    name: "[intent-name]-dialog-context",
    parameters {
        "height": ""
    }
}
```

I have to deal with negative flow. Suppose this is the conversation

BOT : What is your height?
USER : 4ft 12 inch
BOT:You said your height is 4ft 12 inch.Please Confirm

In this case  "height" is parameter and if User respond as YES we should proceed to next question but if user says NO then I need to clear the value of parameter "height" and bot will repeat the same question. Using above code, I tried to clear the height. But It's not working.

Comment: I'm sorry, I may missing something here but If you repeat the question the value will be replaced with what the user respond on the second time no need for clearing the parameter value, have you tried this?

Comment: i tried the above approach,the value is getting inserted in next parameter instead of getting override

Comment: Could anyone find any solution for the same?